# protobuf-net build v2.0.0.580 not able to serialize System.Xml.Linq.XElement

Tags: protobuf-net

I just replaced the previous protobuf-net build which I was using in my code base (version 2.0.0.480) with the latest build (version 2.0.0.580) - since there is no specific build against .Net 4.0 or .Net 4.5 in the latest protobuf version, I am referencing the net30 full dll in my projects.

When trying to serialize a complex type which includes a System.Xml.Linq.XElement I get an InvalidOperationException from the protobuf serializer - the exception message states : 
"No serializer defined for type: System.Xml.Linq.XElement"

I am assuming that the lack of a serializer for XElement relates to the fact that there is no .Net 4.0 build (since I'm referencing v4.0.30319 of the System.Xml.Linq.dll in my project).

My project targets the .NET 4.5 platform - it works fine when referencing the protobuf-net V2.0.0.480 net40 build.

Comment: This has nothing to do with 4.0; the reason I don't have a 4.0-specific build is because it *doesn't use any 4.0-specific types/methods*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *looks* like it is related to "parseable types" - things that don't have inbuilt handling, but which meet certain patterns allowing them to be treated as a `string`. This has caused a few problems in the past, so is *optionally* supported, via `.AllowParseableTypes`:

```
static void Main()
{
    XElement el = XElement.Parse("<xml />");
    var model = TypeModel.Create(); // store and re-use this; don't use
    model.AllowParseableTypes = true; // a new one each time! (very bad)

    var foo = new Foo { Bar = el };
    var clone = (Foo) model.DeepClone(foo);
    var cloneEl = clone.Bar;
}
[ProtoContract]
class Foo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public XElement Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the reason I had to declare a `Foo` here is that it looks like the "root object" handling (which is quite different to handling members / sub-objects) isn't checking for parseable types; I'll have to investigate why not and fix it. I would *hope* that the following would work (it doesn't currently, but probably should):

```
static void Main()
{
    XElement el = XElement.Parse("<xml />");
    var model = TypeModel.Create(); // store and re-use this; don't use
    model.AllowParseableTypes = true; // a new one each time! (very bad)

    var cloneEl = (XElement)model.DeepClone(el);
}
```

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks a lot for your quick response - I decided to simply change my business logic: instead of transmitting an Xelement via my WCF service, I serialize the XElement as string prior to utilizing the protobuf-net serialization engine - on the server side I'll parse the string back into an XElement representation. I changed the protobuf contract attributes accordingly, it was a very quick fix. I should have thought of this before instead of wasting your precious time.

Comment: Marc is there any further progress / other workarounds for this now?  I'm attempting to convert a legacy code base to use Protobuf-net and right near the end (of course) I've bumped into an XElement member which is returning the same exception as the OP for version 2.0.0.622

Comment: @Shaun does the above help?

Comment: @Marc - It certainly stops the exception being thrown but the "caused problems in the past" and "(very bad)" comments had somewhat put me off just adopting this approach, especially as it applies to the whole model and not just that specific member, that's why I asked if there were any other work arounds.  But of course I'll take your word that it's the way to go till experience proves otherwise :)

Comment: Ahh, I now see the "very bad" comment was about regenerating the model, sorry about that.

Comment: @Shaun the "problems" apply only when applied without conscious intent, to types where it isn't really appropriate; the "very bad", as you note, applies to creating a new model every time